# Invalid JWT Signature

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I know. I know. LOTS of questions with this exact title. But of all the ones I've looked at, I can't find one that is creating the JWT using a `List<Claim>`, an `issuer` and an `audience`.

```
    private string GetTokenString()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim("claim1", "foo-anything"),
            new Claim("claim2", "bar-anything")
        };

        string keyValue = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";  // NOT THE REAL KEY (changed for this SO question)
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyValue));

        var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken
          (
              issuer: "https://xxxxxx.net",
              audience: "https://www.xxxxxx.com",
              claims: claims,
              signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
              expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
          );

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        string tokenString = handler.WriteToken(jwtToken);

        return tokenString;
    }
```

Then if I take `tokenString` and plug it into https://jwt.io/, I get

> Invalid Signature

Is there something wrong with the way I'm creating the JWT?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter for the signature verification which claims you have in the payload. But you have the ' Secret base64 encoded'  checkbox checked, while in your code you nowhere decode it. Seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the base64 encoding of your signing key

```
1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

comes out to be this

```
MTIzNDU2Nzg5MHF3ZXJ0eXVpb3Bhc2RmZ2hqa2x6eGN2Ym5t
```

Please use this value to validate the generated token, in this case the check box should be checked.

If you leave the check box blank then use the same value as you have in your code.

Comment: It will validate with the original string if that box is unchecked.  I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I still get "invalid signature" with the check box unchecked, or with it checked with the base64 encoded value in the field.

Comment: Everything still seems to work on the receiving end of this token. It all validates just fine. Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: @casey Crookston , I have updated the answer hope it is clear. Just to reply to your last query , yes it should be fine . Just make sure that in production  , the exchange of shared key is done securely with the validating client .